# How can I define a type in TypeScript that's a string that only should contain words from a predefined list

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, tailwind-css

I have a tricky TypeScript question.

Let say I have this Icon component with the prop size. Size can be "2", "4", "6". I map these values to predefined tailwind classes.

So I type it like

```js
type SizeValues = '2' | '4' | '6';

function Icon({size = '4'}: {size: SizeValues}) {
   const sizeMap = {
     '2': 'w-2 h-2',
     '4': 'w-4 h-4',
     '6': 'w-6 h-6',
   };
 
   return <span className={sizeMap[size]}>My icon goes here</span>
}

<Icon size="sm" />
```

Everything is fine. But what if I wanna have different sizes depending on what screen size I have. So I wanna try to have like tailwinds nice syntax.

So I rewrite my Icon component to following:

```js
type SizeValues = ???

function Icon({size = '4'}: {size: SizeValues}) {
   const sizeMap = {
     '2': 'w-2 h-2',
     '4': 'w-4 h-4',
     '6': 'w-6 h-6',
     'md:2': 'md:w-2 md:h-2',
     'md:4': 'md:w-4 md:h-4',
     'md:6': 'md:w-6 md:h-6',
     'lg:2': 'lg:w-2 lg:h-2',
     'lg:4': 'lg:w-4 lg:h-4',
     'lg:6': 'lg:w-6 lg:h-6',
   };
 
   return <span className={size.split(' ').map(s => sizeMap[s]).join(' ').trim()}>My icon goes here</span>
}

<Icon size="2 md:4 lg:6" />
```

That works fine, but how do I type it? I read TypeScript will support regex in the future. That will make it easier, but is it possible to type this now?

This is not a real component so please don't give me awesome suggestions how I can improve it. I just wanna know how I can type my size prop so it works the way I've coded it.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WYQ9zW) work for you? It also checks for duplicate classnames. If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: I mean! Wow! That was awesome! Yeah duplicates are now allowed. Thank you so much. Must say typescript are really hard when it gets more complex.

Comment: Hmm if the size value have a default string of '2' how would the function look like then? It says i cannot have a default value.

Comment: are you expecting only single className as the default value?

Comment: I made a more fully [example](https://tsplay.dev/wQ06VW) how I would like to use it

Comment: I would like it to work with either a single value or with a space separated string.

Comment: If its easier to write, a duplicate value is okey. I basically want a typescript function that says that these words can be in this string. Duplicate or not.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N5x8Pw) work then?

Comment: Yeah it works, however i looses the autocomplete on the Icon component. It only suggest '2' now. Can it be made so it works with all of the values?

Comment: I made it a little bit better. Now I have autocomplete on the first value at least. But not on the rest of the words. I do have 2 errors in my code though
https://tsplay.dev/NDd6RN

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it will be possible to support autocomplete

Comment: I would suggest creating a separate question for fixing the errors inside the component. I know how to fix them; ping me if you do. Otherwise, should I write an answer here?

Comment: Yeah just write the answer here! i think its a good answer. I just wanted the other goodies

Comment: Okay, will write the answer later today

Comment: I ended up making it an string or an array and just simple
size?: IconSizeValues | IconSizeValues[];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we need to extract `sizeMap` into the global scope, and [const assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) it to let the compiler know that this is immutable constant and restrict  it from widening types:

```
const sizeMap = {
  '2': 'w-2 h-2',
  '4': 'w-4 h-4',
  '6': 'w-6 h-6',
  'md:2': 'md:w-2 md:h-2',
  'md:4': 'md:w-4 md:h-4',
  'md:6': 'md:w-6 md:h-6',
  'lg:2': 'lg:w-2 lg:h-2',
  'lg:4': 'lg:w-4 lg:h-4',
  'lg:6': 'lg:w-6 lg:h-6',
} as const;
```

Next, we need to get a type for the keys of the `sizeMap`:

```
type SizeMap = typeof sizeMap;
type SizeMapKeys = keyof SizeMap;
```

Implementation:
We will create a type that accepts a string and returns it if it is valid; otherwise, return `never`.

Pseudo-code:

Let type accept `T` - string to validate, `Original` - original string, `AlreadyUsed` - union of already used keys.

If `T` is an empty string

- return `Original`
  Else if `T` starts with keys of the size map (`ClassName`), excluding `AlreadyUsed`, followed by a space and the remaining string(`Rest`).
- Recursively call this type, passing `Rest` as a string to validate `Original`, and the `AlreadyUsed` with `ClassName` added to it.

Else if `T` is the key of the size map excluding `AlreadyUsed`

- return `Original`
  else
- return `never`

Realization:

```
type _SizeValue<
  T extends string,
  Original extends string = T,
  AlreadyUsed extends string = never
> = T extends ""
  ? Original
  : T extends `${infer ClassName extends Exclude<
      SizeMapKeys,
      AlreadyUsed
    >} ${infer Rest extends string}`
  ? _SizeValue<Rest, Original, AlreadyUsed | ClassName>
  : T extends Exclude<SizeMapKeys, AlreadyUsed>
  ? Original
  : never;
```

We have to add a generic parameter to `Item` that will represent the `size`.

```
function Icon<T extends string | undefined>({
  size,
}: {
  size: _SizeValue<T>;
}) {
  return null;
}
```

Since, `size` is optional in the component, we will add a wrapper around the `SizeValue` which will turn `string | undefined` to `string` and pass it to `_SizeValue`, additionally we will add a default value for size:

```
type SizeValue<T extends string | undefined> = _SizeValue<NonNullable<T>>;

function Icon<T extends string | undefined>({
  size = "2",
}: {
  size?: SizeValue<T> | "2";
}) {
  return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
<Icon size="2" />;
<Icon size="md:2" />;
<Icon size="md:2 md:6" />;
<Icon size="md:2 md:6 lg:6" />;

// expected error
<Icon size="md:2 md:6 lg:5" />;

// no duplicates allowed
<Icon size="2 2" />;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGd47gAvJAWRTDgF44BvcnAIAmfAC4CAdwC0wuAAtZ+ADSCCAFnFTp6hTpVr8ANi34ZRvSdVD8IACZjRE2w5lz7YxaOsEPm5x4yuh6Kmj4uYiYBrtIWIbEGNgA2AOaOpqlibnCZXokEmf4FaUE5aaH5+JlRxVmxZZ4JqgC+cCh0cNT0MBTkMACeYEhwAMos7Jw8cANDEJhwTKwcYBQzw2NLnADSSP0dvADWu3Oj48u9a3AA+htIAGooSQCuSAA8agAqcEgAHjBINDsHQYUGANBSPgA8qCUmDHt8-gCgQsYKDwVMPj4AIJJIgoOz9ACqdCQdgR-0BwNRYJSUxoSAAbkgoKoAHwY8lIjr4fBqAD8cGhwFhNEeagkX1+FORAAMACR8MGYZlwADCSXadAAcigQMMpVy4ABRH5oZ52N5qIRCW7LHZ7HzWuA4vEE4mkq1wVmtBVKlXIBicykotEpZoy-nXW4PZ5vAMwZSCmFwpKJl2oN0kskAHzVGro2t1SFZ4rgksRwZNZqeFtetu2uzoadxGaJWZLQgFQpFYqEEnpTKgF0G63GMZer3L0qpobguaegKQmDBpPZvBuY8eE61tC1TySGoARkk3h9WazepgFxhgLQ4ABJLqToPIkE0udwBcW5f0uysgAUfALOMUz4KIcDNBIQGLEgfISNGW6nuyuZgfgEEAJT8GoRAwE8UA0HAND7kkFDNJQryPneMHcAARMINFwAA9Be5AUV0wGsLRHj0UxLFsVR4xcQ47gOEYDHMRQ-EEdRNHcXAHgWNU4kseQjGMQiQwYKS3xQDgUCsZR0mCbJwnyaJDQAKzKb0amERAcB2E8YBJMAaAoP8HSPEkECSB6UkcUgtFyDxEnkEAA)